# Why some image search questions are upvoted?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions, down-votes, up-votes

Image identification-request is one of the most useful features of Anime and Manga StackExchange, when you are getting at the end of "Google-Image-Search".

Here an [example](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18463/what-is-this-picture-of-a-smiling-man-from).

But sometimes I see questions like these:

- [What anime is this winking girl from?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4282/what-anime-is-this-winking-girl-from/4283#4283)
- [What anime is this male character with brown hair and pierced ears from?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8322/what-anime-is-this-male-character-with-brown-hair-and-pierced-ears-from?rq=1)
- [Anyone know what anime this gif is from?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7512/anyone-know-what-anime-this-gif-is-from?rq=1)

... which you could easily solve with Google reverse image search. All these questions above get upvoted or answered.

**Therefore I'm asking: Why some image search questions which could easily be solved with Google gets upvoted, instead get downvoted like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nKUZ.jpg). Both are the same kind of questions but get different votes.**

Comment: If someone sees an image they also want to know the origin of, they may upvote it regardless of how easy it is to find.

Comment: In addition to the other reasons here, it's important to note that, at least early in the site's history, the frequency of image-based identification questions was low enough that many of the regulars didn't know or care that such questions could be answered easily via reverse image search. While that is common knowledge now, it's only because the number of such questions increased drastically, and so [a meta post](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/793/) was made, which is now prominently displayed when an asker uses [tag:identification-request].

Answer (score 2):

The [first](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4282/what-anime-is-this-winking-girl-from/4283#42830) and [second](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8322/what-anime-is-this-male-character-with-brown-hair-and-pierced-ears-from?rq=1) are indeed lazy questions. However, people from other sites who are unaware of the reverse image search feature will upvote them when the question gets featured on the hot network questions list. Same for new users who are unaware of reverse image search feature.

For the [third question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7512/anyone-know-what-anime-this-gif-is-from?rq=1), just specify the image in reverse image search doesn't give any usable result, and it's probably necessary to do reverse image search on some frame in to get the desired result.

(I'm assuming only Google Reverse Image Search, since it is the only thing featured in the warning. General users don't read and search meta before asking question.)

There are only a handful of users who are aware of the feature **and** bother to vote on [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions, so if the question gets exposed to new users and users from other sites of the network, it will get their upvotes.

The next vote also depends on the current score (upvotes + downvotes) of the question, due to the mob mentality. This may explain the case with the image you cited at the end.

Comment: The third question I also easily could find with Google

Comment: @Andruseto: Really? When I reverse search with Google, I can only find a bunch of image sites, and not tagged with the series name. If it is not clearly on first page, it can be considered somewhat hard to find.

Comment: http://xxalex-your-godxx.deviantart.com/art/HOMESTUCK-GIF-6-326513321 Search on this site for the title of this anime: "Nabari no Ou". The user "thesumnang" leave there a comment.

Comment: The problem is that the users are'nt smart and patient enought to search deeper. The reward for thier lazieness are votes.

Comment: @Andruseto: We want some minimal effort from user to do reverse image search. As long as the search result is not clear, it makes a valid question. The website you cited appears on the 3rd page in my search, so it is rather inaccessible, in my opinion. I would usually stop at the first page anyway.